# Prevent Web API from adding application/json to Content-Type header

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, content-type

I have a .NET Web API method that returns multiple files via a `MultipartContent`. The Content-Type of the response should be `multipart/mixed; boundary="some_boundary"` based on how I initialize the `MultipartContent`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFiles() {
        var content = new MultipartContent("mixed", "some_boundary");
        // add multiple StreamContent objects...

        return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = content, };
    }
```

However the actual content type in the response is `multipart/mixed; boundary="some_boundary",application/json`. Is this valid? How can I prevent `,application/json` from being added?

I only need to apply a fix to this one method because my controller has other methods that do return JSON. I do not want to change the content-type of their responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How can I prevent `,application/json` from being added?**

It turned out this happened because the Content-Type header was being set by Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Not sure why that line was there but I determined that it was not necessary. After removing that line, my response returned a content-type header of `multipart/mixed; boundary="some_boundary"` which is what I wanted.

**Is `multipart/mixed; boundary="some_boundary",application/json` a valid content type?**

I believe the answer is no, it is not valid, or at the very least it causes unpredictable behavior. Using .NET as the client, a response with that content-type resulted in `HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType` being null, however I could still access the header via `HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Where(h => h.Key == "Content-Type")`.